# How does partition-by identity dedupe collections in clojure?

Tags: clojure

The following clojure code dedupe elements in a vector:

```
user> (partition-by identity [1 2 2 3 3 3 4 2 2 1 1 1])
((1) (2 2) (3 3 3) (4) (2 2) (1 1 1))
```

1. How does it accomplish the dedupe?
2. How can I see, step by step, how the resulting collection is built?

Comment: `partition-by` doesn't deduplicate anything, it just splits a sequence into subsequences based on what `f` returns for each value in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen it yet, be sure to bookmark [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).

Clicking on `partition-by` [takes you ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by) with good info & examples.

Click in the upper-right to see [the Clojure source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7080).  Look at the 2nd arity that takes a function `f` and a collection `coll`:

```
 ([f coll]
     (lazy-seq
      (when-let [s (seq coll)]
        (let [fst (first s)
              fv (f fst)
              run (cons fst (take-while #(= fv (f %)) (next s)))]
          (cons run (partition-by f (seq (drop (count run) s))))))))
```

So `fst` is the first item in the collection, and `fv` is the transformed value using the function `f`.  It then consumes all items that match `fv`, at which point it recurses with the first non-matching item.